# How to write a Series object to .txt without quotes around string lines?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to export a Series object to a text file, in which the text file needs a very specific format.
Content of series are rows in which all columns of a dataframe are concatenated, each with a very specific length (padded with either spaces or 0s). Because of this, each line is a string.

Format rules:

1. All lines should be exactly the same length. Meaning that shorter values should be padded with either spaces (alphanumeric) or 0s (numeric)
2. Output should be a flat file (.txt)
3. Content of input can't be adjusted

Used code:

```
IPGJ_flat = IPGJ['period']
IPGJ_flat.to_csv('20201119_DAF IPGJ Test.txt', index = False)
```

Sample Output (Fake)

```
ABCDEFGHIJK
"LMNOPQRST123456789         abcdf,gh,i           abcd"
"UVWXYZABC123456789         abc,def,gh           abcd"
UVWXYZABC123456789         abcdefghij           abcd
```

Needed output:

```
ABCDEFGHIJK
LMNOPQRST123456789         abcdf,gh,i           abcd
UVWXYZABC123456789         abc,def,gh           abcd
UVWXYZABC123456789         abcdefghij           abcd
```

Quotations are only applied if there is rows where there is a ',' present.

I've already tried the following:

```
IPGJ_flat = IPGJ['period'].to_frame()
IPGJ_flat.to_csv('20201119_DAF IPGJ Test.txt', index = False, sep = '|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar = ' ')
```

With variations of seperator and escapechar, but this seems to mess up the formatting (new lines aren't identified correctly).

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: What's the type of your period column?

Comment: Period column is an object type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use a CSV function (`.to_csv()`) for something that's clearly not CSV. So why not just write it to file, without treating it as CSV?

```py
import pandas


# Recreating your test data
s = pandas.Series([
    "LMNOPQRST123456789         abcdf,gh,i           abcd",
    "UVWXYZABC123456789         abc,def,gh           abcd",
    "UVWXYZABC123456789         abcdefghij           abcd",
], name="ABCDEFGHIJK")


# Open a file to write to
with open("test.txt", "w") as f:

    # Write the header to file
    f.write(s.name)
    f.write("\n")

    # Construct the content and write it to file
    content = "\n".join(s)
    f.write(content)


# For demo purposes, show the content of the file
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: This solved it, thanks! Made a small adjustment to not also print the Series name to the file.

Answer (score 0):

try 'to_string' instead of 'to_csv':

`IPGJ_flat.to_string('20201119_DAF IPGJ Test.txt', index = False)`

(read up on DataFrame.to_string()) for more options.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It seems to cut off the lines when they are too long with '...' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the answer from Gijs Wobben, I solved it with the following:

```
for item in IPGJ_flat:
    with open('Test.txt','a') as f:
        f.write(item)
        f.write("\n")
```